# Vim silent launch of ConEmu (into Git Bash) - Windows 7 Command Prompt seizes

Tags: windows, command-line, git, gvim, conemu

From a Windows 7 Command Prompt:

```
ConEmu.exe /cmd "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i && exit
```

opens ConEmu (or a new tab therein) logged into Git Bash for the current directory, and (very quickly) exits the Command Prompt window, *all good*.

From gVim:

```
:silent !ConEmu.exe /cmd "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

1. if ConEmu was already running, opens a new tab logged into Git Bash for the buffer's directory, and exits the intermediary Command Prompt window, and returns me to my current buffer, *all good*.
2. if ConEmu was not running, it's opened logged into Git Bash as above, **but the intermediary Command Prompt window is left up  in a seized state**, requiring me to terminate it to unfreeze gVim.  (Appending `$$ exit` to the above gVim command doesn't help.)

**The Question:** How can I fix the 2nd gVim case, such that the Command Prompt window called by gVim closes automatically as in the 1st gVim case?

---

Supplementary gVim info (responding to @Maximus):

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug 29 2014 07:03:32)

Sysinternals' `Process Monitor` `Filter`'d for `Operation` `Process Start` finds that this heirarchy of Commands, all labelled "(ConEmu.exe)", are triggered by `:!ConEmu`:

1. `"C:\Program Files\vim\vim74\vimrun" C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c`
2. `C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c`
3. `C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe  /c`

`vimrun.exe` is not in %PATH%.

---

Alternative attempt from gVim, using [win32-!start](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_w32.html#gui-shell-win32):

[Don Reba at Vim Wikia explains](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Execute_external_programs_asynchronously_under_Windows):

> if you enter a command like :!calc (to run calc.exe for the Windows calculator), Vim will open a shell window, then launch a new calc window from that shell. When calc is closed, the prompt Hit any key to close this window... appears, and Vim is frozen until a key is pressed. But Calculator is a GUI program so it runs in a new process, in a new window. So, if you want to asynchronously run a GUI program like Calculator, you can simply enter :!start calc

So I tried:

```
!start ConEmu.exe /cmd "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i && exit
```

- which doesn't seize gVim and opens a new ConEmu tab in Git at gVim's working directory, but fails to login, reporting `sh.exe": &&: No such file or directory`, followed by:

> Command to be executed: "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i && exit
>   ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=127.
>   Press Enter or Esc to close console...

Comment: 1. Question unclear. 2. `sh.exe": &&: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @Maximus, I've attempted to clarify the question (on the last line). I can't make sense of your 2nd point.

Comment: When I run `:silent !ConEmu.exe` from gVim there is no "command prompt window", only ConEmu.

Comment: @Maximus, I've just tried that on my ancient `N130`, and (maybe because it's so slow) there is, for about one second, a Command Prompt window.  Run just `:!ConEmu`, and you'll see that CP window stating "Hit any key to close this window...", which is necessary to now unfreeze gVim.

Comment: gVim version. Show screenshot. Run ProcessMonitor and look for `Process Start` events. What is started?

Comment: @Maximus, sorry, I need reputation at least 10 to post screenshot of the seized CP window.

Comment: `:help win32-vimrun`. So you need `silent` if you do not want to get cmd window. BTW, I have no `vimrun.exe` in `%PATH%` and cmd window does not appear at all :)